# Javacv: Mat data becomes null after using methods

Tags: java, android, opencv, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm working on an android application for object detection and counting. For the image processing I am using JavaCV (Java wrapper for OpenCV and FFmpeg). After importing the library, I'm able to successfully use the FFmpegFrameGrabber to get the frames of a video.

**My problem:** After I convert the Frame to a Mat object and perform some operation on that Mat object the data becomes null.

**Code:**

**MainActivity**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat converterToMat = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToMat();


    private CountModule countModule;
    FFmpegFrameGrabber retriever;

    ArrayList<opencv_core.Mat> frames;
    boolean frameloaded = false;

    File folder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
    File video = new File(folder, "test.mp4");

    AndroidFrameConverter converterToBitmap = new AndroidFrameConverter();



    private static WebStreamer webStreamer;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLdFrames);
        final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((TextView) button).setText("Loading");
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            button.setClickable(false);
                            button.setAlpha((float) 0.3);
                            LoadFrames();
                            button.setAlpha((float) 1);

                        } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });
    }
    private void LoadFrames() throws FrameGrabber.Exception {
        if (!frameloaded){



            frameloaded = true;

            retriever = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(video);
            frames = new ArrayList<>();
            Log.d("Frame",": Start of loop");

            retriever.start();
            final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            for (int i=0;i<50;i++){//155430
                retriever.setFrameNumber(i*100);
                Frame temp = new Frame();
                temp = retriever.grab();

                frames.add(converterToMat.convert(temp));

                Log.d("Frame",": " + i*100);



            }
            retriever.stop();

            countModule = new CountModule(frames);
            Log.d("Frame","CountModule instantiated");

        }
    }
}
```

**Constructor of Countmodule**

```
public CountModule(ArrayList<Mat> frames){

    fgGBG = new Mat(frames.get(0).rows(),frames.get(0).cols(),frames.get(0).type());
    gbg = createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2();
    Mat maTemp = new Mat(frames.get(0).rows(),frames.get(0).cols(),frames.get(0).type());

    median = new Mat(frames.get(0).rows(),frames.get(0).cols(),frames.get(0).type());
    frames.get(0).copyTo(median);
    ;
    median = getMedian(frames);
    kernel2 = Mat.ones(11,11,CV_8U).asMat();
    kernel = Mat.ones(3,1,CV_8U).asMat();
    gbg.apply(median,fgGBG,0.001);

}
```

**Variables (images):**

[After convert from Frame to Mat. Data has values.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7CSD.png)

[Data=null when using the method frame.copyTo(median). Data of Mat also null when using method Mat.ones()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F9d6.png)

---

As you can see everytime I use a OpenCV specific method, the returned Mat is not what is expected.

Comment: Why don't you use [OpenCV for android](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/)?

Comment: At the start I used the OpenCV4Android sdk, but then I needed FFmpeg so I switched to JavaCV.

Comment: Ok I haven't coded in JavaCV but I went through an example on GitHub, [may be you are doing it wrong](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/blob/master/samples/HoughLines.java)

Comment: Also, take a look at [this](http://bytedeco.org/news/2015/04/04/javacv-frame-converters/)